# Grammar of a C++ Translation Unit

Tags: c++, grammar, declaration

My understanding, for a long time now, was that *a C++ translation unit*, after the preprocessor has run, *is a sequence of declarations* (let me remind that any definition is also a declaration).

Many people have argued with this statement but no one has ever given a counterexample. But I myself found this example which troubles me:

```
int x;       //declaration

;            // ??? EMPTY DECLARATION?

int main()   //dec
{            //la
}            //ration
```

This compiles fine with MSVC and online comeau. I know the standard defines an ***empty statement*** but I never heard of an empty declaration. So, I see three options:

- My understanding is correct and the standard defines an empty declaration
- My understanding is correct but the standard doesn't define empty declarations and the above translation is ill-formed
- My understanding is incorrect, i.e. a C++ TU is not a sequence of declarations

Please help me dissolve my doubts. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An *empty-declaration* is allowed in (the current draft of) C++0x at file scope (and namespace scope and other places where a declaration is allowed) and it is just a semicolon. It is a standalone grammatical entity.

In C++03 a lone semicolon is not allowed where only a declaration is expected. Although it might appear that a *simple-declaration* might be able to reduce to just a semicolon an explicit rule disallows this.

7 [dcl.dcl] / 3

> In a simple-declaration, the optional *init-declarator-list* can be omitted only when declaring a class (clause 9) or enumeration (7.2), that is, when the *decl-specifier-seq* contains either a *class-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier* with a *class-key* (9.1), or an *enum-specifier*.

In short this implies that the *init-declarator-list* can be omitted only when the *decl-specifier-seq* is not omitted.

Comment: So, my claim is correct in C++0x but is incorrect in C++03, is that it? Or rather, my claim is correct in both, but in C++03 my example is ill-formed? Which one are you implying?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: According to my interpretation, yes, but as with everything in C++ I await being corrected ;-) .

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment, it now asks A or B, so "yes" isn't a valid answer :)

Comment: You edited your comment, for clarity: your example is ill-formed because it violates a diagnosable semantic rule of C++03. It is / will be well-formed C++0x, however.

Comment: . Hmm.. this seems to make sense. But indeed you are right, this is C++, nothing is clear enough. So Let's wait and see if someone else corrects you with yet another useful quote :). If not, I will sure accept your answer

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Your understanding is correct and the standard (or at least Stroustrup) does define an empty declaration</strike>.

**EDIT**: It seems this answer is wrong (there's a semantic rule on the standard - but not on the book, as far as I can tell - that prohibits both `decl-specified-seq` and `init-declarator-list` of being empty at the same time). See Charles Bailey's answer.

---

n "The C++ Programming Language", appendix A, section A.4:

> A program is a collection of `translation-unit`s (...). A `translation-unit`, often called a *source file*, is a sequence of `declaration`s:

```
translation-unit:
   declaration-seq_opt
```

`opt` means the production is optional. In this rule, it means an empty translation unit is valid.

Section A.7:

```
declaration-seq:
    declaration
    declaration-seq declaration

declaration:
    block-declaration
    (...)

block-declaration:
    simple-declaration
    (...)

simple-declaration:
    decl-specified-seq_opt init-declarator-list_opt ;
```

So `declaration-seq` is a sequence of at least one `declaration`. A `declaration` can, amongst other things, be a `block-declaration`, which in turn produces `simple-declaration`. As both the `decl-specified-seq` and `init-declarator-list` non-literals are optional, `;` is a valid declaration.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the standard, so Stroustrup is as far as I can go.

Comment: Not true, see [dcl.dcl] / 3. "In a _simple-declaration_ the optional _init-declarator-list_ can be omitted only when declaring a class or enumeration..." to be in one of these cases the _decl-specifier-seq_ cannot be empty. This is still true in C++0x but in C++0x there is an additional explicit _empty-declaration_ so a lone semicolon is valid.