# Shall a C++ class function end with a }; or only a }?

Tags: c++, syntax

A basic questions about C++ syntax.

Shall a c++ function end with a ; or does it not matter?

Or what is the difference between those two examples?

With a ending ;

```
void Test :: print()
{
  ...
};
```

Without ;

```
void Test :: print()
{
  ...
}
```

I have seen C++ code both with and without, 
but I don't get the difference.

/Thanks

---

**Update**:

In this case the ; should be avoided since it is not doing anything useful and may even become a problem in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grammar of a C++ Translation Unit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335024/grammar-of-a-c-translation-unit)

Comment: I disagree, that question is kind of related but not really the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Outside of a class body (where a function definition may optionally be followed by a single `;`), a function definition is terminated by the end of a *compound-statement* - that is the closing `}`. At namespace scope, the next token after the closing brace of a *function-definition* must form part of the next declaration.

In C++03, there is no such thing as an *empty-declaration* so placing a `;` is illegal, although accepted by many implementations. (Although the syntax of a C++03 *simple-declaration* appears to allow a missing *decl-specifier-seq* and a missing *init-declarator-list*, leaving just a `;`, there is a semantic rule forbidding both optional parts to be left out expressed in 7 [dcl.dcl] / 3 of the standard.)

> In a simple-declaration, the optional *init-declarator-list* can be omitted only when declaring a class (clause 9) or enumeration (7.2), that is, when the *decl-specifier-seq* contains either a *class-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier* with a *class-key* (9.1), or an *enum-specifier*.

C++0x introduces an *empty-declaration* (which is a declaration with no effect), so you can have as many rogue `;` at namespace scope as you like although there is no good reason to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed adding empty declarations to your file when you put in spurious semicolons. It does not matter much, as @Space_C0wb0y pointed out.

BTW, the heading does not fit your question.

Answer (score 2):

No. The sign ; should not be the end of the function.
Perhaps you've seen sign at the end declaration class