# Semicolon after Function

Tags: c++, syntax

Is there a specific reason why some people put a semicolon after the curly closing function bracket?

```
void foo() {

};
```

Comment: Maybe they want to get consistency with class definitions? This is not the best idea, I think.

Comment: C++ semicolon is used to tell the compiler where a statement ends. The body of a function or any scope block isn't a statement in and of itself so it's pretty much only needed after `}` when defining an object. Having extra `;` or empty statements doesn't particularly hurt but may generate warnings or errors on some compilers.

Comment: I would suspect copy/paste errors, or a misunderstanding that they are unneeded.

Comment: Maybe someone was trying to hint poor syntax highlighting.

Comment: @AJG85: Grammatically, function body is an ordinary compound statement. However, compound statement never ended in a `;` in C++.

Comment: as a javascript guy, I just feel paranoia whenever I use c/cpp. therefor I spam the semicolons.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not really, the semicolon there makes no difference. It's probably a matter of habit.

You can put as many semicolons if you want though in C++11:

```
void foo() {

};;;;;;;;
```

Comment: @LuchianGirgore: The "empty declaration" was introduced in C++ 11. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335024/grammar-of-a-c-translation-unit

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487849/shall-a-c-class-function-end-with-a-or-only-a

Comment: @CharlesBailey I didn't know that. Ok... It's just a case of MSVS being overly-lenient again.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Not just MSVS, I think.  I've used other compilers which accepted empty statements outside of a function definition as well.  (An of course, it's always been legal for function definitions inside a class.)

Comment: Empty definitions are OK in namespace scope, but not in class scope. In class scope a *single* `;` has always been allowed by the grammar (i.e. it is *not* really an empty definition in that context). Adding more than one trailing `;` in class scope will result in an error.

Answer (score 8):

Why they do it is probably purely a matter of personal style (and a rather strange one, I'd add). But the legality of this is a completely different matter. In pre-C++14 versions of the language it depends on the scope in which this function definition is made.

If you define such function in *namespace* scope, then the trailing `;` has nothing to do with the function definition. In C++98 and C++03 it would simply be a syntax error. C++11 introduced (or "legalized") so called *empty declarations* in namespace scope (but not in class scope). So, that extra semicolon simply constitutes a separate empty declaration, which follows the function definition. This also means that in namespace scope you can add as many extra superfluous semicolons as you wish.

If you define such function in *class* scope, then it is a different story. In all versions of the language (starting from C++98) you have always been allowed to add a *single* optional `;` at the end of an in-class function definition. Such `;` is an integral part of the function definition and it is explicitly allowed by the grammar. I.e. in class scope that trailing `;` does not constitute an independent empty definition. This also means that in class scope you can only add one optional `;` after function definition, but not more.

However, in C++14 in order to resolve some issues caused by that optional `;` in class method definitions C++14 re-designed this part of the grammar. Now the grammar for in-class member function definition no longer contains the aforementioned optional `;`. Instead, starting from C++14 classes now support empty member declarations as well. So, the meaning of that redundant `;` is now consistent across all scopes: it is just an independent empty declaration tacked on at the end of a function definition.

So, to summarize the above with an example

```
struct S
{
  void foo()
    {};      // <- Legal and has always been legal
  void bar()
    {};;     // <- Legal starting from C++14, error before that
};

void baz()
{
};           // <- Legal starting from C++11, error before that
```

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon must follow the class definition curly closing bracket. It is not required after class member functions definitions inside of the class definition. It is required though after class member functions declarations alone inside of the class definition.

```
#ifndef FRAME_COUNTER_H
#define FRAME_COUNTER_H

#include <iostream>

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

const Uint32 FPS = 60;
const Uint32 DELAY_TIME = 1000.0f / FPS;


class FrameCounter {

public:
    FrameCounter();

    void setFPS(int FPS) { m_FPS = FPS / (m_frameAccumulator / 1000); }

    void start() { m_frameStart = SDL_GetTicks(); }

    void run();

    void reset() {}

    void print() { printf("\nFPS: %5.1f\n", m_FPS); }

private:
    int m_frameNumber;

    Uint32 m_frameStart;
    Uint32 m_frameDuration;
    Uint32 m_frameAccumulator;

    double m_FPS;
};

#endif
```

Comment: To be clear, it must follow the class definition, but is not required  *inside* the class after class member function definitions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to ask the *specific* people. But if I had to guess: in C++ there are situations, when you have to put semicolon after `}`, like class, enum, struct - so maybe some people put it always, because they don't want to remember when it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it is simply ignored.  Looks like a typo.