# run a program with more than one source files in GNU c++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, compilation, gnu

I am using DEV GNU c++ compiler on windows 7 OS. I need to know how a program with more than one source file can be compiled.
here is example,

```
#FILE1
void f1()
{
   printf("this is another file under same program");
}

#FILE2

int main()
{
   f1();
   return 0;
}
```

Actually I need this to test how static, extern class specifier works with more than one file. So only I have to learn now how works with more than one files in a single program in C..

Thanks advance

Comment: I guess you need to create a project (in your IDE) and build _that_. Add both files to the project. It is unclear to me what IDE you are actually using. Bloodshed/DevC++? C++ Builder? Embarcadero?

Comment: Shoudn't any file contain a main() method??

Comment: @A_nto2: no your whole project need exactly one `main()`

Comment: @Thomas: ok, you're right! :)

Answer (score 3):

The technical term for 'multiple files' would be ***[translation units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335024/grammar-of-a-c-translation-unit#4337554)***:

```
g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp -o program
```

Or you separate compilation and linking

```
g++ -c file1.cpp -o file1.o
g++ -c file2.cpp -o file2.o

# linking
g++ file1.o file2.o -o program
```

But that usually doesn't make sense unless you have a larger project (e.g. with `make`) and want to reduce build times.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to precise the two files on the command line of `gcc`:

```
gcc file1.c file2.c
```

Comment: please you explain what I have to exactly do... I am on windows 7.

Comment: @alaminhosain How do you compile a single cpp file?

Comment: Start a command prompt (`cmd.exe`), change to the directory that contains the files, and type the command above.

Comment: @sehe with keyboard ctrl+f9 single cpp file opened

Answer (score 2):

To preprocess and compile as such:

```
gcc -c FILE1.c
gcc -c FILE2.c
```

Then, to link:

```
gcc -o EXECUTABLE FILE1.obj FILE2.obj
```

Alternately, you can do both in one step:

```
gcc -o EXECUTABLE FILE1.c FILE2.c
```

If it's a C++ program, then replace the `gcc` by `g++` and the `.c` by `.cpp`.

It does not interest you, but for the benefit of similar readers who find your question later, `FILE1.cpp` may be named `FILE1.cc` or the like, and `FILE1.obj` may be named `FILE1.o`, depending on the reader's platform.

It may interest you that, depending on the shell you are using, you might have to write options like `-o` as `/o`.