# C++: Minimal header undefined reference

Tags: c++, codeblocks, header-files, undefined-reference

Using a **very** simple source and header file setup (main.cpp, callbacks.h and callbacks.cpp) I get an error message saying: `Undefined reference to "error_callback(int, char const*)"`. It seems some have run into the same problem, but not with quite as simple circumstances, which is what has really thrown me off.

Here are the files:

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "callbacks.h"

int main(void){
    char er[] = "Error.";
    error_callback(1, er);
    return 0;
}
```

callbacks.h:

```
#ifndef CALLBACKS_H
#define CALLBACKS_H

void error_callback(int error, const char* description);

#endif // CALLBACKS_H
```

and finally callbacks.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "callbacks.h"

void error_callback(int error, const char* description){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}
```

I cannot possibly imagine a simpler header file setup - yet something's gone wrong. I'm 99.9% sure I've managed the header and source files correctly.

**EDIT**

It seems it was an issue with the IDE Code Blocks. Source files will show in the directories even if they are not properly linked in the project. Manually adding every file again resolved the issue.

Comment: Did you add `callbacks.cpp` to the files that need to be compiled?

Comment: ^-- And linked?

Comment: If you used GCC then compiled Like this: g++ main.cpp callbacks.cpp

Comment: Show the command line command you use to build the code.

Comment: Maybe CALLBACKS_H has defined somewhere. Try different define like ____CALLBACKS_H____

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn - Very bad suggestion. Identifiers starting with a double underscore or an underscore followed by a capital letter are **all reserved** for the implementation.

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't know that. Just want to sugest him to try different indentifier. MY_CALLBACKS_H

Comment: @PhạmAnhTuấn that's an OK header guard. Still, I think it is unlikely the problem because we can clearly see from the code that `CALLBACKS_H` is not declared anywhere else. Only file that is not shown is `<stdio.h>` which is guaranteed to not define `CALLBACKS_H`. Only possibility left is that Felix has explicitly asked the compiler to define it.

Comment: Perhaps [Run a program with more than one source file in GNU c++ compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155327/run-a-program-with-more-than-one-source-files-in-gnu-c-compiler) will help.

Comment: It was an issue with the IDE. Check the edit for details. What a "feature".

Comment: But thank you for the input everyone! I should just trust the errors.

Comment: @Felix Feel free to write an answer to your own question explaining the issue and accepting it. [Self-answering is encouraged here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!